# Подскажите хорошее решение для многопоточной обработки txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Eсть txt, допустим 1000 строк. Нужно при помощи threading, например, в 50 потоков обработать (взять строку, передать в функцию, удалить строку). На ум пришло поместить весь файл в список, и через list.remove() удалять обработанные строки. Но дело в том, что потоки видимо мешают друг другу, из 1000 итемов в списке обрабатывается ~700 и скрипт гоняет пустой список, не завершаясь (хотя проверка на длину списка есть). Создавать копию txt и удалять из нее строки- я думаю костыль.
Вопрос: как по дзену Python нужно реализовать этот скрипт?

Comment: Разделите список на 50 маленьких списков и раздайте потокам. Изменять один объект из разных потоков нельзя без синхронизации потоков

Comment: Мультипроцессинг пул имап. Трединг не даст прироста.

Comment: @eri зависит от задачи, а она в вопросе не описана

Comment: пробую разделить на части список, в принципе сейчас вопрос как раз таки в организации данных для обработки, но про мультипроцессинг я понял, принял, подумаю

Comment: Хорошим решением для распределенной обработки TXT будет использование `Spark` кластера. Файл должен будет лежать на распределенной файловой системе, например `HDFS` ;-)

Comment: решил проблему разделением списка на несколько, всем спасибо за советы!